# Why if $B=M^{-1}AM$ the columns of $M$ are eigenvectors of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I know that $A$ is diagonalisable if exists a diagonal matrix $B$ such that $B=M^{-1}AM$. Somewhere I read that the columns of M are eigenvectors of A. Why is that? Also, is $M$ uniquely defined?

Comment: I guess you're assuming that $B$ is diagonal?

Comment: Yes, $B$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be an Eigen vector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$ and let the Eigen vectors be independent of each other.

$$A{X_i} = \lambda_i{X_i}$$

Let  $\color{green}{M = [{X_1} \  {X_2} \cdots {X_n}]}$ which contains the columns with the Eigen vectors of $A.$

So, $$AM  = [A{X_1} \  A{X_2} \cdots A{X_n}] = [\lambda_1{X_1} \  \lambda_2{X_2} \cdots \lambda_n{X_n}]$$

$$AM = [{X_1} \  {X_2} \cdots {X_n}]\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\0 &\lambda_2 &\cdots & 0
\\ \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots &\lambda_n \end{bmatrix} $$

$$\color{blue}{AM = MB}$$

$B$ is the diagonal matrix. $M$ is invertible as the *Eigen vectors are independent* and $\color{red}{|M| \not= 0}$.

So,

$$\color{blue}{M^{-1}AM = B}$$

> Now $M$ need not be uniquely defined, as corresponding to an Eigen value we have infinitely many Eigen vectors.

**So, we generally normalize the vectors by dividing them by their magnitudes to obtain $B$ as the diagonal matrix with the Eigen values of $A$.**

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia: In linear algebra, a square matrix A is called diagonalizable (or nondefective) if it is similar to a diagonal matrix, i.e., if there exists an invertible matrix P such that $P^{−1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.

It happens that when a matrix is diagonalizable, you can form $P$ by finding matrix $A$'s eigenvectors. You can calculate $P^{-1}$ from this then.

The intuition is that eigenvectors are those that when applied with linear operator indicated by $A$, the operator would only serve as a dilation of the vector. A matrix is diagonalizable essentially means that the eigenvectors serve as a complete basis for which space $A$ as a linear operator takes input from and gives output to.

Think about this intuition and write down the equations in matrix form of this statement. It would look like $Ax = Dx$ where D is diagonal. Then go for the proof from here. (There is one last step I didn't write out for you to figure out for fun.)

Answer (score 0):

This is stitching together various definitions with different perspectives on matrix multiplication.

1. If $A$ and $M$ are matrices such that $AM$ is defined, the $j$th column of the product matrix $AM$ is $A$ times the vector in the $j$th column of $M$.
2. If $M$ and $B$ are matrices such that $MB$ is defined and $B$ is diagonal, then the $j$th column of $MB$ is the $j$th column of $M$ scaled by the $j$th entry along the diagonal of $B$.

If those two facts aren't obvious, try it out with a few small examples to see why.

A vector $m$ is called an eigenvector of $A$ with (scalar) eigenvalue $b$ if $Am = bm$.  If there is a basis of eigenvectors $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_n$ with eigenvalues $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$, then $A m_j = b_j m_j$.  In other words, for each $j$, then $j$th column of $AM$ equals the $j$th column of $MB$.  That is, $AM = MB$, which, since $M$ is invertible (remember its columns are a basis), means $B = M^{-1}AM$.

No, $M$ is not uniquely determined by $A$.

- We could permute its columns any way we like, and we would still have $M^{-1} A M$ diagonal.
- Even if the eigenvalues which make up the diagonal elements of $B$ are fixed, any column of $M$ can be scaled by a nonzero constant, and we would still have $M^{-1} AM=B$.
- If any of the eigenvalues appears more than once, we can substitute for each of the columns of $M$ corresponding to a repeated eigenvalue, any linear combination of those eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have $$AM=MB$$ where $B$ is a diagonal matrix.

Columns of $AM$ are simply the result of multiplying the matrix $A$ by columns of $M$

On the other hand columns of $MB$ are the diagonal elements of $B$ multiplied by the columns of $M$

Thus we get $$AV=\lambda V$$ for each column $V$ of $M$ where $\lambda$ is a diagonal element of $B$

For the uniqueness of $M$ the answer is no because you may multiply an eigenvector by a scalar and it is still an eigenvector.